# Commandline arguments in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, parameters

In linux I can do something like this:

```
rm test.txt -f
```

On Mac however, I get the following error:

```
rm test -f
rm: -f: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In what way is it broken ?

Comment: I want to be able to execute <command> <filename> <argument> on Mac osx terminal in the same way it works on ubuntu.

Comment: Then you might want to go to work for apple and fix it there. Otherways, you want to do `rm -?` and see what commands are actually available on Max OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got the syntax backwards.  It should be:

```
rm -f test.txt
```

In most cases, the options come before the files because there may be a variable number of them.  Take for instance:

```
chown file.txt joe   # this is wrong
```

you can see if this was the order you could only operate on one file, whereas the proper order of arguments lets you do this:

```
chown joe file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

It is analogous in your case.

Comment: okay, but why is `rm test.txt -f` working in every linux? (tested on debian and ubuntu)

Comment: Ubuntu uses gnu rm which supports the syntax you desire.  OSX doesn't. You could add gnu rm to your system and then it would work.  You could do this by "brew add coreutils" (assuming you use brew, or via macports or fink)